# Turn to the pages marked classified

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

### (Looking for a job)

**Boy**: Oh, where can I find a real job?

**Mom**: Well, you can start by looking in the newspaper.

**Boy**: Where in the newspaper?

**Mom**: In the classified pages. Turn to the pages **marked** classified.

---

What does "Turn to the pages **marked** classified" mean?

Does it mean "Turn to the pages **written** classified"?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

*Turn to the pages [**which/that are**] marked **as being** [the "classified advertisement" pages]*.

The speaker knows or assumes that as well as having a ***page number*** written in small print at the top or bottom of each page, there's also some kind of "section" text ("News", "TV listings", "Sport", "Classified Ads", etc,), making it easy to leaf thru to the required section.

---

Note that ***the classified pages / the classified ads / the classifieds*** means *small advertisements placed in a newspaper and **organized in categories***. So there are usually a number of "subject headings" within that section of the newspaper - second-hand articles of various types for sale, personal services, rooms to rent, etc.

Answer (score 0):

@FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica answer's is great.

You can also say:

> Pick up the classifieds.

> Turn to the classifieds.

with **the classifieds** [being](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/classifieds) "the collection of small advertisements in a newspaper, magazine, or on a website, organized, for example, by available jobs or types of things for sale".

Comment: Haha - while you were composing your answer, I was editing in an extra section to my own, wherein I explicitly put up ***the classifieds*** as one of the idiomatic ways of referring to this section, and gave my own equivalent definition!